# How to resolve 'Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Location unknown is not yet publicly available' error processing Cloud DataPrep job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm running a Cloud Dataprep job, which has successfully run many times until today.

It now fails with an error when creating the 'temp_dataset_beam_job_...' dataset.

The error is Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Location unknown is not yet publicly available'.

Can anyone give guidance on how I correct this/set a location for the temp datasets and check the permissions?

The trifacta service and compute accounts for this project have Edit permission on the source dataset within BigQuery, and also have Cloud Dataflow Service Agent and Dataprep Service Agent roles on the Google Cloud project.

Thanks

Angus

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a missing permission on the downstream Big Query project. 
In addition to the Dataprep project that you're building your flow in, you need to make sure that the trifacta account (service-*@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com) has big query editor permission on the Big Query project that you're creating the temporary tables in.